# Why GORM is using methodMissing

Tags: grails, groovy, metaprogramming, grails-orm, abstract-syntax-tree

As I read [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+methodMissing+and+propertyMissing), grails is using methodMissing to inject GORM methods to the domain classes, but having said that methodMissing are expensive to execute cause only occur in the case of failed dispatch, why those methods are not injected via metaClass or AST Transformations? Any clues?

Comment: As of Grails 2, most methods are added using an AST. The dynamic methods (findBy*, findAllBy*, etc) aren't because as @sbglasius points out it's better to add those on-demand

Comment: Ok, so as far a I understood sbglasius and Tomasz are both correct, aren't they? I mean Tomasz points that some methods are added by AST, but as sbglasius points not the dynamic finders.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using methodMissing is not that expensive, since Grails creates a new methode in the MOP only at the first execution of a methode not found. The sub-sequente executions takes place on the newly created methode.

Consider a domain class with many properties. If all findBy*, findAlLBy*, countBy* etc permutations should be created at compile time, the classes could easily become VERY large. By using the methodeMissing, only methodes actually used at runtime will be created.

Answer (score 5):

As I understand the code, this information is outdated. These methods are injected to metaClasses. Take a look at the code for grails-hiberante plugin.

`HibernateGrailsPlugin.groovy` ([github](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-hibernate-plugin/blob/master/HibernateGrailsPlugin.groovy)) line 49 executes each time context starts:

```
def doWithDynamicMethods = HibernatePluginSupport.doWithDynamicMethods
```

Then, open up a `HibernatePluginSupport` ([github](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-hibernate/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/orm/hibernate/HibernatePluginSupport.groovy)) and follow the flow:

```
/*451*/ static final doWithDynamicMethods = { ApplicationContext ctx ->
    def grailsApplication = application
    enhanceSessionFactories(ctx, grailsApplication)
}

/*456*/ static void enhanceSessionFactories(ApplicationContext ctx, grailsApplication, source = null)
// calls in line 464:
/*464* enhanceSessionFactory sessionFactory, grailsApplication, ctx, suffix, datastores, source
```

This closure is crucial inside `enhanceSessionFactory` method:

```
/*548*/ def enhanceEntity = ...
```

And it is called for every entity in lines 581-583. Methods are generated from line 587 in method `registerNamespaceMethods`. And as I understand it correctly these methods are injected to metaClass directly starting from line 597:

```
    def classLoader = application.classLoader

    def finders = HibernateGormEnhancer.createPersistentMethods(application, classLoader, datastore)
    def staticApi = new HibernateGormStaticApi(dc.clazz, datastore, finders, classLoader, transactionManager)
    dc.metaClass.static."$getter" = { -> staticApi }

    def validateApi = new HibernateGormValidationApi(dc.clazz, datastore, classLoader)
    def instanceApi = new HibernateGormInstanceApi(dc.clazz, datastore, classLoader)
    dc.metaClass."$getter" = { -> new InstanceProxy(delegate, instanceApi, validateApi) }
```

Please revise and correct me if I'm wrong. I'm not that confident that it is all correct. These are only my findings while reading a Grails source code.